# Appending USING ~<~ to ORDER BY

Tags: python, django

I am trying to order non-English author list alphabetically using PostgreSQL as backend database.

These are my models:

```
class Alphabet(models.Model):
    letter       = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    letter_spell = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    order        = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.letter

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

class Author(models.Model):
    slug              = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    name              = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    biography         = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ...
    alphabet          = models.ForeignKey(Alphabet)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

Unfortunately, that's not ordering them correctly.

So I went to terminal, typing:

```
SELECT * FROM authors ORDER BY name
```

Didn't give the desired result. However, this is working:

```
SELECT * FROM authors ORDER BY name USING ~<~
```

So how can I append that to my ORDER BY clause?

Note that my view code as follow:

```
a = Alphabet.objects.all().prefetch_related('author_set')
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/) or [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) the default one. The original code for default ordering is in `https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py` in the `get_ordering()` function. I don't see any way to add easily a `USING` clause in a query.

By the way if Django is not ordering correctly maybe is a bug.